# How to lock z rotation in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get mobile controls working in unity but when i try to look left and right the camera tilts slightly, so i want to lock the z rotation but i can't.

```
using UnityEngine;
using DitzeGames.MobileJoystick;
namespace DitzeGames.MobileJoystick.Example
{
    public class BoxMover : MonoBehaviour {


    public Transform transform;
    protected Joystick Joystick;
    protected Button Button;
    protected TouchField TouchField;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake ()
    {
        Joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();
        Button = FindObjectOfType<Button>();
        TouchField = FindObjectOfType<TouchField>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 
    Joystick.AxisNormalized.x * Time.deltaTime * 3f, Button.Pressed ? 2 : 1, 
    transform.position.z + Joystick.AxisNormalized.y * Time.deltaTime * 3f);
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, TouchField.TouchDist.x);
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, TouchField.TouchDist.y);

    }
}}
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

just add a rigidbody and lock the z rotation, and turn off gravity. you  can set its collider to trigger so it dosnt hit anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I wrote for completely locking camera rotation without using a RigidBody. Just create this script and add it to your camera (or whatever you want to lock).

```
public class RotationLock : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Quaternion lockedRotation;
    
    void Start() { lockedRotation = transform.rotation; }
    void Update() { transform.rotation = lockedRotation; }
}
```

Here's another version that lets you choose which axes to lock. I wrote it for a 3D phone game where the user could rotate their view in place by swiping.

```
public class RotationLock : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool lockX, lockY, lockZ;
    private Vector3 startRotation;

    void Start() { startRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles; }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 newRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
            lockX ? startRotation.x : newRotation.x,
            lockY ? startRotation.y : newRotation.y,
            lockZ ? startRotation.z : newRotation.z
        );
    }
}
```

There may be more efficient solutions, but these work in a pinch and won't involve the physics system!

Comment: Thanks so much, your RotationLock script worked flawlessly when I needed a simple solution ASAP!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding code that will reset the tilt of the camera at the end of each frame.

```
var rot = transform.rotation;
Camera.main.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(rot .x,rot .y, 0, rot .w);
```

Comment: thats not how quaternions work ... if you want to set angles directly use euler angles instead `Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, rot.y, 0);`

Comment: I added `
    var rot = transform.rotation;
     Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, rot.y, 0); `

to FixedUpdate and it gives errors like NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DitzeGames.MobileJoystick.Example.BoxMover.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/MobileJoystick/Scripts/Example/BoxMover.cs:28)

Comment: @Edward2005 Do you have your Camera tagged as MainCamera? But I only answered in respect to the lines above my post. If the snipped you posted is attached to your Camera, you dont need the whole `Camera.main.` thing, just use `transform.rotation`. (edit: also careful, i just realized you named a field transform, MonoBehaviour already has a transform field, so that will get overriden)